# REACT JS: How to add a Key to an array that hasn't been initiated, inside a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, array-map

I been trying for a few days to solve this piece of code and have successfully slowly progress through it but I'm still stuck sadly here's the issue:

First of all what I want to achieve is to display an Array of X with all the values starting on 1 someone gave me a hint and I try it but it doesn't seem to be working and is Probably because I'm not assigning a "key" to it

`const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState( new Array(libros.length).fill(1) );`

This is supposedly will create an array with all values starting on 1 if I'm not wrong.

but this is what is printing:

[image]

when I manually assigned 1 as a value at least to the first one it looks like this:

[image]

But since I'm manually just setting up  `const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState([1]);` it clearly won't work because is just the first value, which is why I try the previous code `const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState( new Array(libros.length).fill(1) );`  but that didn't work sadly (or maybe I'm just missing the key component), because that's the error it gives me (I'm not even using li/list though) here's where it sends me is basically a list/key information but it seems that key is the equivalent of my "index" value I gave in the start [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

[image]

Anyways moving on, The idea is to increases the amount/cantidad of the number with 2 functions called `mas` and `menos`, is quite simple if you click the button on the left it adds + 1 and if is the one on the right it does -1 that I think is covered correctly:

```
const mas = (index) => {
        setCantidad(cantidad[index] + 1);
      };

      const menos = (index) => {
        if (cantidad[index] > 0){
            setCantidad(cantidad[index] - 1);
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Sorry, Zero limit reached");
            setCantidad(0);
        }
      };
```

Finally this is how I'm printing the table

```
<tbody>
                {libros.map((libros, index) => (
                        <tr >
                        <td>
                            <button onClick = {() => mas(index)}/>
                            {cantidad[index]}
                            {console.log(cantidad)}
                            {console.log([index])}
                            <button onClick = {() => menos(index)}/>
                        </td>
                        <td>{libros.grado}</td>

                        <td >
                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        {libros.descripcion}
                        </td>

                        <td >{libros.editorial}</td>
                        <td >${parseFloat(libros.precio).toFixed(2) * cantidad[index]}</td>
                        </tr>

                     ))}
                </tbody>
```

This is what the console log is showing:
[image]

I have read [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and I understand the basics on a regular situation didn't saw a similar example of my current situation any help/tips is appreciate it, here's my actual code (whole code):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth, db } from './firebase';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Checkbox } from '@material-ui/core';

function CrearPedidos({user}) {
    const [libros, setLibros] = useState([]);
    const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState( new Array(libros.length).fill(1));

    const history = useHistory("");
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState();

    const librosRef = db.collection('libros');
    const queryRef = librosRef.where('grado', '==', '4° Grado');

   console.log(cantidad)

    useEffect(() => {
        queryRef.orderBy("precio")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setLibros(tempData);
          });
      }, []);

      const mas = (index) => {
        setCantidad(cantidad[index] + 1);
      };

      const menos = (index) => {
        if (cantidad[index] > 0){
            setCantidad(cantidad[index] - 1);
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Sorry, Zero limit reached");
            setCantidad(0);
        }
      };

    return (
        <div className="listado_Pedidos"> 
        <div className="estudiantes_container">
            <h1 className = "estudiantes_container_h1">Estudiante: {user.displayName}</h1>
            <h1 className = "estudiantes_container_h1">Libros Nuevos</h1>
            <div className ="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="Lista">
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Grado</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Editorial</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {libros.map((libros, index) => (
                        <tr >
                        <td>
                            <button onClick = {() => mas(index)}/>
                            {cantidad[index]}
                            {console.log(cantidad)}
                            {console.log([index])}
                            <button onClick = {() => menos(index)}/>
                        </td>
                        <td>{libros.grado}</td>

                        <td >
                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        {libros.descripcion}
                        </td>

                        <td >{libros.editorial}</td>
                        <td >${parseFloat(libros.precio).toFixed(2) * cantidad[index]}</td>
                        </tr>

                     ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div className="space" />
            <button onClick="{realizarPedidos}" className = "crear_estudiante_boton">Realizar Pedidos</button>
            <div className="space" />
      </div>

      </div>
    )
}

export default CrearPedidos
```

I know I been doing lots of questions lately buuuut I wanna learn and practice all I can, oh also I'm using Firebase for my database the only value that is not from the database is cantidad/amount all the others grado/course descripcion/description, etc are from the database which is why I haven't had issues with those.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question but you can use some tricks to generate ID in-place. Using `nanoId` node package or `Date Object` in `JS` -> *`new Date().getTime().toString()`*

Comment: Correct me if I'm understanding, but you want the rows to go 1, 2, 3, 4....

Comment: @Andrew I want all of them to be 1, cantidad/amount is the amount of books you would like, so it will start with 1 if you wanna add more books of the same then it goes to -> mas/plus and menos/minus which are the 2 buttons.

Comment: @ErfanMotallebi I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but I have found the below problem in your code.

You are setting the default value to the `cantidad` state using another state `libros` but it'll be set only once when your component renders for the first time.
So you should use `useEffect` hook here to update the `cantidad` whenever `libros` change.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setCantidad(new Array(libros.length).fill(1))
}, [libros])
```

Always use keys when looping over some array and rending list of component.

```
{libros.map((libros, index) => (
    <tr key={libros.id || index}>
      ...
    </tr>
)}
```

Comment: This could work, but why do we need to create a new array every time a new book is added or changed? I think this is bad for performance and doesn't seem intuitive / good practice.

Comment: This worked, but w/e I try to use the functions ```mas```  or ```menos```  it goes back to blank idk what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Instead of setting value 1s when new `libros` is added you need to just add 1 at end of the array.
So inside use effect check that both arrays have different lengths add 1s at the end or remove the propert value.

Comment: Question @SangamRajpara why does the functions are not working, did I set them up wrong ?